# How to create a folder in python?

Tags: python

I am running a code in python where I get images from input file, and create another folder as output and a file csv. The code that I run is as below:

```
# import the necessary packages
from PIL import Image
import argparse
import random
import shutil
import glob2
import uuid

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required = True,
    help = "input directory of images")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required = True,
    help = "output directory")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--csv", required = True,
    help = "path to CSV file for image counts")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# open the output file for writing
output = open(args["csv"], "w")

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in glob2.iglob(args["input"] + "/*/*.jpg"):
    # generate a random filename for the image and copy it to
    # the output location
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg"
    shutil.copy(imagePath, args["output"] + "/" + filename)

    # there is a 1 in 500 chance that multiple copies of this
    # image will be used
    if random.randint(0, 500) == 0:
        # initialize the number of times the image is being
        # duplicated and write it to the output CSV file
        numTimes = random.randint(1, 8)
        output.write("%s,%d\n" % (filename, numTimes))

        # loop over a random number of times for this image to
        # be duplicated
        for i in range(0, numTimes):
            image = Image.open(imagePath)

            # randomly resize the image, perserving aspect ratio
            factor = random.uniform(0.95, 1.05)
            width = int(image.size[0] * factor)
            ratio = width / float(image.size[0])
            height = int(image.size[1] * ratio)
            image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

            # generate a random filename for the image and copy
            # it to the output directory
            adjFilename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".jpg"
            shutil.copy(imagePath, args["output"] + "/" + adjFilename)

# close the output file
output.close()
```

After running the code I get only csv file, but I don't get output folder. 
The way I run the code is:

```
python gather.py --input 101_ObjectCategories --output images --csv output.csv
```

Please can you help me how to solve the problem, because I need the output folder for next steps, running next functions.

Comment: Have you looked into [os.mkdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir)?

Comment: The error I get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\code\gather.py", line 31, in <module>
    shutil.copy(imagePath, args["output"] + "/" + filename)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '....\\database/8403e077-3fd5-4d65-9f45-ada5fab36f9b.jpg'

Comment: That error seems to be related to the file you are trying to move, not necessarily the folder you've created

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the following approach:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

Path('path').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

This works cross-platform and doesn't overwrite the directories if they already exist.

Comment: You don't need to `os.path.join`. You can just do `Path("directory/directory").mkdir(...)` as `pathlib` will normalize this.

Comment: Yes it does, hence why I said "`pathlib` will normalize this." :-) Try it out: https://repl.it/repls/ExcitableTameSpools

Comment: Oh, wow, you're right! Let me delete the comment and edit the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should try the `os` module. It has a `mkdir` method that creates a directory based on the path you give it as a parameter.

```py
import os
os.mkdir("path")
```

Answer (score 3):

While most answers suggest using `os.mkdir()` I suggest you rather go for `os.makedirs()` which would recursively create all the missing folders in your path, which usually is more convinient.

```
import os
os.makedirs('foo/bar')
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs